# Does random linear transformation keep linear indepedence?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory

We have 3 linearly independent vectors $J_1, J_2, J_3 \in \mathbb{C}^3$. We also have a random matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{4\times 3}$. Are the vectors $AJ_1, AJ_2, AJ_3 \in \mathbb{C}^4$ linearly independent? In other words, Does the random linear transformation from $\mathbb{C}^3$ to $\mathbb{C}^4$ keep the linear independence almost surely?

Comment: This doesn't have to do with probability; it is a simple matter of finding a contradiction.

Comment: @DonLarynx How so?

Comment: @Igor: http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/probability/info

Comment: @DonLarynx I still don't see where any sort of a contradiction is involved.

Comment: @Igor: Okay - but this question still doesn't have to do with probability.

Comment: @DonLarynx I am connecting this with the probability aspect, because it is apparently if the matrix the answer to this question is NO in general. But, I am seeking for the answer when the matrix A has all of its elements drawn from some continuous distribution, which might make the answer is Yes, almost surely, or with probability one.

Comment: @DonLarynx I might be wrong in my tag so, I am quite new to this site I am sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes (but you have to define what you mean by "random matrix") You don't even need to go to $\mathbb{C}^4$ - $\mathbb{C}^3$ works fine, since under most definitions of randomness, the determinant of a random matrix is non-zero.

Comment: The random matrix is a matrix whose elements are drawn independently from some continuous random distribution. I know that the answer sounds more straightforward when $A\in \mathbb{C}^3$, but the thing is that the problem I am solving has this transition to $\mathbb{C}^4$ where am not so sure of the answer!

Comment: @Meemo I think it's a property of continuous random distributions that any set of Lebesgue measure zero has probability zero of being selected, in which case the answer to your question is yes, because the set of singular matrices has measure zero.

Comment: @Dustan Levenstein The matrix $A\in \mathbb{C}^4$ is not square though. I am assuming that you mean by singular matrix here that it doesn't have its maximal rank (which is 3 here), Am I right?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realize there was a dimension mismatch in the problem. It's the same reasoning though; the set of matrices for which $A J_1, A J_2, A J_3$ are linearly dependent has measure zero.

Comment: @Dustan Levenstein By the same reasoning, Can I say that the first three rows of the matrix, $[AJ_1\;AJ_2\;AJ_3]\in \mathbb{C}^{4\times 3}$, are linearly independent almost surely?

Comment: Adding another row does not make it less likely that things will be independent; rather the opposite...

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the matrices such that the first three rows are linearly independent already form an open and dense set (because they're just $GL_3\times M_{3\times 1}$, so a product of an open dense set and the entire space if you see $M_{3\times 4}$ as $M_{3\times 3}\times M_{3\times 1}$).

The set of all matrices of maximal rank is even bigger. In fact, the set of all matrices such that *any* three rows are linearly independent is also open and dense with much the same proof.

Comment: open and dense does not imply the complement is a null set.

Comment: But the complement *does* have measure $0$.

Comment: @tomasz I don not get this very well since my knowledge about measure theory is not that perfect. I just want to know if your comment implies that the first three rows of the matrix $[AJ_1\;AJ_2\;AJ_3]$ are linearly independent?